# Retrive decimal values from table using mysql Like query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve records from table, all the records are decimal values in (width x Height) format

using like clause I want to to get data but query  didn't work  for it

```
Table:

id   widthheight

1     17.14X12.41

2     23.4X39.8


select * from test where widthHeight like '%17X12%'
```

Comment: You should think about your table design. Store the data in two columns not in one.

Comment: If you cannot change your table design (which you should!), you can try and use a regular expression (cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Comment: @Jens but I want  to match decimal value with non decimal based on that records should come

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said above, create two columns 'width' and 'heigth'

```
select * from (
select 
    id, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(widthHeight, 'X', 1) width,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(widthHeight, 'X', -1) height
from mytable) x
where floor(x.width)=17 and floor(x.height)=12
```

Your original query was not working because you should have done this:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where widthHeight like '%17%' and widthHeight like '%12%'
```

Comment: Note that this answer also have poor performance. You should really create two columns.

Comment: And, when you create separate columns, than you should not do `where floor(width)=17`, but something like `where width between floor(17.14) and ceil(17.14)`. In this last case an index on `width` can be used.

Answer (score 4):

Better solution is to use a regex query:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE widthHeight REGEXP '17(\.\d+)?X12(\.\d+)?'
```

This regexp will match with following values:

```
17X12
17.14X12.41
17.00X12.00
17.9999999X12.999999
```

You can playground with this regex on the [awesome Regex101. Go to this link.](https://regex101.com/r/4SJ89E/1)

**Note:** This query won't be efficient. Consider splitting your data into two columns named `height` and `width` that uses [`DECIMAL` column type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) so you can do more efficient queries.

Comment: thanks it  worked for me, can you please explain this query

Comment: It uses a regular expression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to select only rows that matches given expression. You can follow the link for regex 101 on my answer, on the top right panel it explains each character on the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally just store the width and height as two separate decimal columns.  That being said, you might be able to work with what you have now using some string tricks:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(widthHeight, 'X', 1) REGEXP '17[[:>:]]' AND
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(widthHeight, 'X', -1) REGEXP '12[[:>:]]';
```